# Is there json schema of json schema?

Tags: json, jsonschema

Is there JSON Schema of JSON Schema? In my app user can upload his JSON schema and I would like to validate it if it's a valid JSON Schema.

Comment: @War10ck: That defines whether it's valid **JSON**, not whether it's a valid JSON **schema**.

Comment: There is a meta-schema at http://json-schema.org/schema (or http://json-schema.org/hyper-schema if you need hyper-schema features).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes. [This](http://json-schema.org/schema) is the meta-schema of JSON Schema draft-04. You can use it to validate whether a JSON is a valid JSON schema.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - it is recommended that schemas reference the schema that they are implementing by declaring a `"$schema"` property. At the time of writing, this is most commonly `"http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#"`

See https://spacetelescope.github.io/understanding-json-schema/reference/schema.html for some discussion about the $schema keyword.